# Strange SSL Errors, only for some

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

There is a strange problem on Apache 2.4.6 httpd!

Some browsers (on PC and Phones) are accepting the SSL certificate at https://www.kamakoti.org/ but some other browsers (on phones) show an error saying certificate is invalid.  One of the users showed a screenshot on examining the certificate on his browser, which shows an older date (Sep 30th)

I renewed the Lets Encrypt certificate. No use.

I enabled the following in apache conf

ErrorLog /home/acharya/logs/ssl_engine.log
    LogLevel info

After which, for the IPs that users reported error for, I see a lot of messages such as

[Fri Oct 29 10:45:54.171874 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 17554] [client 183.82.28.156:6625] AH01998: Connection closed to child 13 with abortive shutdown (server in.kamakoti.org:443)

And in apache error log, I do not see any errors

I also see several successful requests done in the access log

Any help will be very much appreciated please!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a bad Certificate Chain, as said by SSLLabs :

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.kamakoti.org

Try removing *SSLCertificateChainFile* from your config.